# Are ADC errors and noise RTI or RTO?

Tags: adc, noise, error

Are ADC errors like DNL, INL, Offset Error, Gain Error and Noise specs given in data sheets RTI or RTO?
The units are LSB so it makes me think they are RTI.

Comment: I assume by "RTI" and "RTO" you mean "relative to input" and "relative to output", respectively.  Given that an LSB only makes sense on the **output** side of an ADC, would a measure in LSB be relative to the input or the output?

Answer (score 1):

Linearity and gain errors are the same on input or output, so it doesn't matter.

For Offset and noise, it depends on the given units. When in Volts, it is RTI. When in bits, it is RTO.

Comment: If an ADC error like offset error is RTO then can it be mapped to the input through  LSB x Vref/2^N

Comment: @Efanatic yup that works